# Is it possible to bind PolyLineSegment.Points through xaml in ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, controls

Recently, I needed to change the Thumb's Template. I want to change its shape to a Triangle like so. I used a Path as its ControlTemplate. Here's the code:

```
 <Thumb
        Width="100"
        Height="30"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Fill="Red">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure>
                                <PolyLineSegment>
                                    <PolyLineSegment.Points>
                                        <PointCollection>
                                            <Point X="0" Y="0" />
                                            <Point X="{TemplateBinding Width}" Y="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                                            <Point X="0" Y="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                                        </PointCollection>
                                    </PolyLineSegment.Points>
                                </PolyLineSegment>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
```

You can see that  I tried to bind PolyLineSegment.Points to Thumb's Width and Height.

But Visual Studio throws an error:

> "Error Object of type 'System.Windows.TemplateBindingExpression'
>
> cannot be converted to type 'System.Double'."

I don't know why it can't work. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found where the problem is. I found it's because `Point.X` or `Point.Y` is not Dependency Property. So that's why binding doesn't work.

I resolve this question by binding to `LineSegment`.

```
 <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0 0">
                                <LineSegment>
                                    <LineSegment.Point>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource thumb2PointConverter}" ConverterParameter="rightBottom">
                                            <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Thumb}" />
                                            <Binding Path="Height" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Thumb}" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </LineSegment.Point>
                                </LineSegment>

                                <LineSegment>
                                    <LineSegment.Point>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource thumb2PointConverter}" ConverterParameter="leftBottom">
                                            <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Thumb}" />
                                            <Binding Path="Height" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Thumb}" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </LineSegment.Point>
                                </LineSegment>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </ControlTemplate>
```